# Aggregate output from Annotation Processors of different buck modules

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing, buck

I have a project composed of several BUCK modules. Each module uses the same annotation processor to generate a single file for each annotated class. For the sake of simplicity, for each annotated class:

```
package com.myproject.module1;

@Marker
public class SomeFoo {
  // ... code ...
}
```

a single class will be generated in the same package:

```
package com.myproject.module1;

@Generated
public class SomeFoo$$Marker {
  // ... generated code ...
}
```

Let's say I have two such modules: `module1` and `module2`

Lastly, I have a `module3` which is dependent on both above-mentioned modules.

This module contains another annotation:

```
package com.myproject.module3;

@MarkerCollector
public class Bar {
}
```

I'm trying to use the same annotation processor (could be a separate one as well), to generate a class that references all previously generated files (due to classes marked with `@Marker`.

The problem is that the annotation processor runs **for each module separately**, when run in module3, **the annotation processor doesn't 'see' the files generated in other modules**.

I've tried using the annotation processor's `Filer` to create a resource file and write the class names of all generated files, but this resource file is too, created **per module**.

**What's the best way to aggregate/access generated code from different modules?**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm currently looking for a similar answer in relation to an Android project with multiple modules.  I've considered allowing the annotation processor to generate each file and then have a Gradle task to copy over into the top tier module all of those files which are then annotated to allow that top tier module to process them into a unified class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with gradle you can create a `JavaCompile` task and configure it as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002072/2057782). My project was targeting android so you will see `variant` just make sure you put your classPath there instead